# Div only hides if same space is occupied by other HTML element - iOS/Safari only

Tags: jquery, html, ios, hide, show

I've made a simple button to login with Facebook, `fbButton` below, but the button only hides in iOS/Safari Mobile using **JQuery** `hide()` and `show()` when the space that it occupies becomes occupied by another element.

I'm having no issues with getting the div to hide when running the page on my laptop (**Firefox and Chrome**), so the issue only exists on iOS.  I haven't tested it on Android or otherwise.

```
<div class="loginSignUp" style="display:none">
    <form>
        <label class="email" for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="email" type="email" id="email">
        <label class ="username" for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="username" id="username">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password">
        <label class="confirmPassword" for="confirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
        <input class="confirmPassword" type="password" id="confirmPassword">
        <div class="formSubmit">Submit</div>
    </form>
    <div class="loginOr">OR</div>
    <div class="fbButton">
        <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" />
        <div class="fbTextHolder">
            <div class="fbText">Log in with Facebook</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, the Javascript is simple - just JQuery `hide()` and `show()`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when the space that it occupies becomes occupied by another element.

Sounds like a z-index issue to me?. Does it happen in landscape mode too? Or try using `.toggle()` instead or `.css('display', 'none');` see if the issue persists.

Comment: Woah, good catch.  It was in fact a z-index issue.  I'd added that to the CSS originally but didn't actually need it and hadn't removed it.  Do you happen to know why it would affect iOS and not Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: Can't really tell without looking at the code but from experience Chrome and firefox are a lot more forgiving specially chrome when it comes to small syntax errors or omissions like forgetting to set the parent element to `position: relative;` etc. When I code I use chrome but always have open other browsers to double check the result.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks!